# Update a many-to-many relationship with TypeORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

I am having issues updating a entity that has a many-to-many reln, curious if I am doing something wrong, or more specifically what is the right way to do this

Consider the following entities ...

```
@Entity
class Subject
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Note, note => note.subjects)
  @JoinTable()
  notes: Note[];

  ...

@Entity()
export class Note {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Subject, (subject: Subject) => subject.notes)
  subjects: Subject[];
```

In my code I find the node and then try to update it and save like so ...

```
const note = await noteRepo.findOneOrFail(noteId);
const foundSubjects = await subjectRepo.findByIds(Array.from(subjectIds));
note.subjects = foundSubjects;
noteRepo.save(note);
```

But alas, the subjects are not saved on the note.

What is the right way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

In my case Im trying to update an existing relation but that gives me a unique key violation because the relation already exists, so I first need to remove all existing relationships and then add the relationships of my updated user:

```
export const updateUser = async (user: User): Promise<User | undefined> => {
    /**
     * Get the actual relationships of that user.
     */
    const actualRelationships = await getRepository(User)
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .relation(User, 'roles')
        .of(user).loadMany();

    /**
     * Add new relationships of the user, and delete the old relationships.
     */
    await getRepository(User)
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .relation(User, 'roles')
        .of(user)
        .addAndRemove(user.roles, actualRelationships);

    /**
     * Update only the table USER.
     */
    await getRepository(User)
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .update()
        .set({
            name: user.name,
            username: user.username,
            active: user.active
        })
        .where('id = :id', {id: user.id})
        .execute();

    /**
     * Return the updated user
     */
    return await getUser(user.id, true, true)
};
```

Comment: It's better to put all these operations in a single transaction

Comment: "Insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint", - error, when i'am using this

Answer (score 8):

So the following got it working for me:

```
  subjectIds.forEach(async id => {
  await connection
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .relation(Note, 'subjects')
    .of(note)
    .add(id);
});
```

Though, I still kind of feel that the repo.save() method **should** work

Comment: So, does this mean we have to write separate queries if there are more changes to be made,  like in Nestor Perez answer?

Comment: You don't need the `forEach`. the `.add` also accepts an array of Ids. Should simplify the code a bit.

Answer (score 5):

By default cascading is set to false, you can enable this as follows:

```
@Entity()
export class Note {
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
id: string;

@ManyToMany(() => Subject, (subject: Subject) => subject.notes, { cascade: true })
subjects: Subject[];
```

Comment: `note.subjects = [{id:1}, {id:2}]; noteRepo.save(note);` will then work.

Comment: this works for adding the new subjects, but what if we want to replace these ids with other ids? Do we have to use the `.relation().of().addAndRemove()`?

Comment: `.save()` does not work even when you're trying to delete an item from to many-to-many junction table.

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer: [How to update an entity with relations using QueryBuilder in TypeORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66794387/how-to-update-an-entity-with-relations-using-querybuilder-in-typeorm)

It worked for me.

```js
...
note.subjects = foundSubjects;
const toUpdate = await noteRepo.preload(note)
noteRepo.save(toUpdate);
```

Don't forget the `await`, is missing in the answer, or is somthing to do with `eager: true`... I'm not sure.