# How to update an entity with relations using QueryBuilder in TypeORM

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have `UserEntity` and `AddressEntity`, they are related as `OneToOne`, that's one user may have only one address. `UserEntity` has fields `firstName`, `secondName`, `address`. `AddressEntity` has fields `country` and `city`.

If I wanted to update `UserEntity` without doing it to its relations I would do this:

```
      await entityManager.getRepository(UserEntity)
                         .createQueryBuilder('users')
                         .update(UserEntity)
                         .set(updateUserObject)
                         .where('users.id = :userId', { userId })
                         .execute();
```

where `updateUserObject` is formed from a request body. That's to say, if I need to update `firstName`, the object would look like this: `{ firstName: 'Joe' }`. Now what is unclear is how to use that builder if I have the following `updateUserObject`:

```
{
    firstName: "Bob",
    address: {
        "city": "Ottawa"
    }
}
```

The official documentation does not address such cases.

Comment: I'm not sure if I correctly understand your question. Do you want to partially update the user without mutating the address?

Comment: you can't update relationships entity,you have to make another query to update the adress

Comment: @sandrooco yes, I'd like to be able to update the user partially. I'm implementing the `PATCH` verb right now for the user entity.

Comment: @Youba So basically, it means that if I have n relations I will have to make n requests or something?

Comment: @Alber no it's not related to requests, you should make another querybuilder for address, like now, you have one for user, you'll add another one for address because it is another entity

Comment: @Youba well I meant requests to the DB. I mean that I have one query builder for user and then to update my user I execute the QB using `await` and then I will fire off another query with one more query builder for the address entity. Am I correct?

Comment: @Alber yes, you right, just to let you know in SQL we should do the same we don't have the ability to update in the same query

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this using [preload](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_repository_repository_.repository.html#preload) and [save](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_repository_repository_.repository.html#save) methods.

Update your `UserEntity` similar to below:

```js
@Entity('user')
export class UserEntity {
  ...

  @OneToOne(
    () => AddressEntity,
    {
      // Make sure that when you delete or update a user, it will affect the
      // corresponding `AddressEntity`
      cascade: true,
      // Make sure when you use `preload`, `AddressEntity` of the user will also
      // return (This means whenever you use any kind of `find` operations on
      // `UserEntity`, it would load this entity as well)
      eager: true
    }
  )
  @JoinColumn()
  address: AddressEntity;
}
```

Now using `entityManager`, you can update all the fields that you want using the following way:

```js
const partialUserEntity = {
    id: userId,
    firstName: "Bob",
    address: {
        "city": "Ottawa"
    }
};

const userRepository = await entityManager.getRepository(UserEntity);

// Here we load the current user entity value from the database and replace
// all the related values from `partialUserEntity`
const updatedUserEntity = await userRepository.preload(partialUserEntity);

// Here we update (create if not exists) `updatedUserEntity` to the database
await userRepository.save(updatedUserEntity);
```

However, you need to make sure that your `UserEntity` has an `AddressEntity` associated always. Otherwise, you will have to generate an `id` for `AddressEntity` like below before you execute `save` method.

```js
/* 
 * If `updatedUserEntity.address.id` is `undefined`
 */

// `generateIDForAddress` is a function which would return an `id`
const generatedIDForAddress = generateIDForAddress();
const partialUserEntity = {
    id: userId,
    firstName: "Bob",
    address: {
        "id": generatedIDForAddress,
        "city": "Ottawa"
    }
};
```

Please note that under the hood, typeorm will run `UPDATE` statements separately for `UserEntity` and `AddressEntity`. This is just an encapsulation of multiple join statements (when executing `preload` method) and update statements (when executing `save` method) such that the developer can easily implement this scenario.

Hope this helps you. Cheers !

Comment: Wow, sounds great! I've already implemented it somewhat differently though but I will try your method later. Perhaps I will have some question. Yaay, thank you! :)